# Eschewmenical blog

Tags: discussion, blog

I've got half an idea for a blog that might be at least interesting.

Take one topic in Christianity (or current events) per month and apply a particular denomination's (or non-denomination's) (or non-christian, but of goodwill) worldview/doctrine to it.

First, we'd agree on a topic here on meta, then we'd decide on 4-5 representatives to write a blog once a week on it.

I was thinking you've gotta be a fully accredited SE site to do this, but I guess they make exceptions.

---

- Please post below with what sort of thing you'd be willing to contribute.  The frequency would probably be once every 1-2 months.

and

- There also would be a need for someone to write an encyclopedic introduction to the months topic.  It might link the pertinent questions from the main site, tag wikis, untranslated Greek and Hebrew, etc...

Comment: several betas have blogs. We've even talked about starting one on gardening :)

Comment: [Is it](http://meta.gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/228/is-there-community-interest-in-an-se-gardening-blog) any closer to coming to fruition?  I'd think now would be a great time to start.!

Comment: Our local paper (The Burbank Leader) has a very similar section.  Each week the editors pick a topic and half-a-dozen local religious leaders provide their thoughts.  Last week's [column](http://www.burbankleader.com/news/opinion/tn-pas-0129-in-theory-the-court-and-faithbased-tolerance,0,3642132,full.story) concerned a recent Supreme Court case.  A more global perspective would probably be in order, but I think the basic idea is sound.  (Non-Christian views ought to be welcomed too, in my opinion.)

Answer (score 7):

I can contribute a Catholic article every month.

---

My qualifications:

- I read a lot of Catholic blogs (NC Register, LifeSiteNews, Zenit, Catholic Culture etc...).
- I listen to a lot of [Catholic radio](http://relevantradio.com/index.php) on my 63 mile commute.
- I have read the Bible (or at least the [Catholic version of "The Way"](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0842322183))
- I teach [middle school Catechism](http://www.staugustinefootville.org/) (which is many years off purgatory)
- I'm a little over half way through a [diocesan training program](http://www.madisondiocese.org/Ministry/EvangelizationandCatechesis/SeatofWisdomDiocesanInstitute.aspx)

Comment: Wait -- a 63 mile commute? What pray tell could possibly be worth a 63 mile commute?

Comment: Well, I've got a good job programming, which is what I love to do, where no one seems to mind if I answer questions on [christianity.se] and above all, it feeds my growing family!  The problem is not being home for dinner most nights, but until I can sell my house for a decent price I'm stuck with the commute. Good thing for [iTunes U](http://www.christendom.edu/news/itunesu.php) and [Librivox](https://catalog.librivox.org/search.php?title=&author=G.+K.+Chesterton&action=Search).

Comment: Oh wow: there are 49 works by Chesterton on Librivox!  I've had problems in the past with less than listenable readers over there.  Do you have any suggestions about which of the Chesterton recordings are worthwhile?  (And I apologize in advance for pulling this more and more off-topic. :-P )

Comment: @jon as far as readers are concerned, the man who was Thursday has a really awesome reader.  I can't remember if he reads the whole thing.  The club of queer trades also had a great reader. But Orthodoxy, the ball and the cross, what's wrong with the world, manalive and tremendous triffles are my favorites.

Answer (score 7):

I love this idea, and I'd be happy to report on either the Baptist or the Episcopalians.  My parents live within a mile of the headquarters of CANA and my church totally straddles the fence between the Episcopal / Anglican divide.  Our church even got a long article in the [Washington Post](http://www.washingtonpost.com/wp-dyn/content/article/2009/07/19/AR2009071901970.html?referrer=emailarticle) that talks about how sensitive this is. (I'm the Michael Hollinger quoted at one point, btw).

Comment: Check out the [Schedule](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1cy4VRQ7oxKcf0UYgXBcZiYR1d-CoEVRL-ozZq0RjvqM/edit) and sign up if you want!

Answer (score 7):

I could take the Bible-thumping-Evangelical position once a month.  <strike>(At a stretch, I could even be Fundamentalist, but I may not fit the stereotype well enough.)</strike>  (For this to work, I think we need to our demonstrate authentic belief and I don't fit all the stereotypes.)

---

Qualifications:

- Was exposed to a wide variety of Protestant clergy in the [Air Force](http://airforce.com/chaplain/) and [Navy](http://chaplaincare.navy.mil/) chapel systems
- Raised, confirmed, and baptized in the Evangelical Covenant Church ([ECC](http://Evangelical%20Covenant%20Church%20%28ECC%29))
- Member in good standing of an [Evangelical Free Church](http://www.emmanuelburbank.org/) ([EV Free](http://www.efca.org/))
- Regular consumer of John Piper's [Desiring God](http://www.desiringgod.org/) resources
- Has lead or been a member of a regular inductive Bible study since college
- Listens to the Bible from Genesis to Revelation every year
- Top contributor to [Biblical Hermeneutics](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=all)
- <strike>Humblest person I know</strike> Up for a challenge

My writing style probably will work better for long-form essays, which I think fits well with a blog format.

Answer (score 5):

I consider myself fairly well read on the philosophical issues of faith and religious commitment. I would love to write a series of blog posts on this topic where I survey Christian thinkers, Jewish thinkers and others (eg: Kierkegaard, [Newman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Henry_Newman), [Pascal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blaise_Pascal), [James](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_James), Descartes, Hume, [Wasserman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elchonon_Wasserman), etc.).

This topic includes:

1. The religious significance of faith and correct beliefs
2. The relationship between scientific empiricism and religious faith
3. The role of ritual in religion
4. The phenomenology of faith
5. Forms of religious commitment

Comment: Ami wrote [the answer](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/203/68) to one of my first questions over on the Hermeneutics site that absolutely got me hooked.  He is an excellent writer and I would love to have him on board.

Comment: Ami mentioned in the [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3545769#3545769) that he's going to wait to see how the blog goes before throwing his hat in the ring.

Answer (score 4):

I'd be willing to write from an Arminian or Methodist perspective. I should be able to contribute an article every month if necessary. I've done a lot of independent study of Christian history, particularly as it relates to my own faith tradition. I also have access to United Methodist doctrinal documents for reference.

Comment: Check out the [Schedule](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1cy4VRQ7oxKcf0UYgXBcZiYR1d-CoEVRL-ozZq0RjvqM/edit) and sign up if you want!

Answer (score 3):

I am willing to post once in a blue moon. I'd be happy to offer perspectives that attempt to step outside of and/or understand both Eastern and Western thought paradigms in Christianity. I'm fine playing devil's advocate on a number of issues, and I'd be happy to write about sacramental / mysterious theology in the one, holy, universal (catholic), and apostolic Christian faith. If you had to pin me down, I'm somewhere in between Lutheran, Anabaptist, and Eastern Orthodox. But really I'm just Christian, perhaps what you might call a neo-Protestant. I have been formally trained in the biblical languages and exegesis/hermeneutics, textual criticism, church history, and systematic theology - but with the exception of the languages and textual studies, I think most of this has harmed my faith more than it's helped it, although today I'm grateful for all of it.

Comment: oic... will edit

Comment: Glad to have you on board, if you want to take the 5th spot for next month's Easter topic we'd be extremely pleased. [Schedule here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1cy4VRQ7oxKcf0UYgXBcZiYR1d-CoEVRL-ozZq0RjvqM/edit)

Comment: Welcome aboard!   When pinning you down means "somewhere in between Lutheran, Anabaptist, and Eastern Orthodox", we know we are getting a unique perspective!

Comment: Yes that is why I originally posted this, was to offer the position of why not to celebrate Easter. Just let me know what I need to do.

Comment: I can't even figure out how to get to the blog since the link isn't at the top of the menu anymore on my screen.

Comment: The link is occasionally at the top and always at the bottom. (It's at the top when there's a new post.)

Answer (score 1):

I offer to write occasionally on topics I am interested about. I offer opinions based heavily around what is written inside the Bible. I do not usually around what is not specifically written inside the bible nor would I reveal my opinions about those kind of topics. The topics I write about include:

- What was written about inside the Bible
- Controversial topics that has biblical bases
- Protestant and Puritan views

Things I do not write about:

- Things not specifically written inside the Bible
- Controversial topics that have little biblical bases or views
- Presbyterian, Catholic, Mormons, etc.