# Would you like to share your story?

Tags: discussion, blog

As y'all might know, Christianity.SE has been running a blog for the last few months.  We've gone over a number of topics: birth control, Easter, the church, Christians at the workplace, and now salvation.  But one of the top-voted topics still left is what I called [Testimony Time™](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1091/914).  I know that some of our users might not be comfortable with that particular phrase, however, so I'm going to re-brand the idea as:

### Your Story

If you participate on Christianity.SE, you must have *some* history with the religion.  For many, it began at birth when you were born to Christian parents.  For some, it began later in life, perhaps at school.  Others, I imagine, have only recently come in contact with the idea of faith in Jesus.  Some of us adhere to one Christian tradition or another, but others have a more intellectual interest.  But all of us have a story.

In order for the blog to be truly Eschewmenical, we need lots of stories form all sorts of perspectives.  Even if you don't consider yourself a Christian or if your conversion story is "boring" we want to hear your voice!

If you participate on Christianity.SE, whether you are a Christian, a non-Christian, an ex-Christian, or any other category we haven't thought of yet, we welcome your contribution.  In order to participate:

1. start writing your story, and
2. contact us by either answering this post or saying "Hi" in the [blog chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2567/eschewmenical-blog-room).

The plan is to run this as a series of posts over a month or two when we get approximately 8 collected. This will be an ongoing series that will just air whenever we have enough volume to merit it. 
Thanks for your interest and let's do this!

Comment: Just to add a bit here. The plan is to run this as a series of posts over a month or two when we get approximately 8 collected. This will be an ongoing series that will just air whenever we have enough volume to merit it.

Comment: In order to be clear, I think you also want non-Christians and "ex-"Christians, too. Right?

Comment: @AffableGeek: "ex-"Christians, yes. Non-Christians...I'm not sure. I'd lean towards "yes".

Comment: AFAIC this is open to anyone who participates in the site.

Comment: Aren't ex-Christians non-Christians by definition?

Comment: @TRiG: agreed, though they are a subset.

Comment: @TRiG: I'll even encourage "pre-Christians" to answer. ;-)

Comment: And the elusive meta-Christian

Comment: Theologically, do "ex-Christians" exist -- or were they never true Christians?

Comment: @Matthew7.7 I'd replace Christians with atheists in that question and consider your response to that question.

Comment: @PeterTurner: I don't understand your statement.

Comment: @Matthew7.7 Atheists consider ex-atheists to have never been true atheists.  That's kind of a preposterous assertion don't you think?

Comment: @PeterTurner: Is it correct to guess that you do not believe in pre-destination and preservation of the saints?

Comment: @Matthew7.7 I think I believe in it as much as St. Paul and St. Augustine did. (at least I'd like to think so)

Comment: If one believes in the preservation of the saints, that Christ holds on to Christians -- then logically, there can be no such thing as "ex-Christians" -- only those who were never Christians in the first place. Am I misunderstanding doctrine here?

Comment: @Matthew7.7 yes, the other way of looking at it is that everyone, more-or-less, is a Christian.

Comment: @PeterTurner: I give up trying to understand your point. If there is actually a question here, please post it as a question.

Answer (score 5):

I would like to share mine.

Couldn't write this month's blog post because the [Python](http://xkcd.com/353/) has decieved me. ;-) :P

Got bogged down with a lotta bugs in my code, (which btw is even more interesting story) but will definitely like to pitch in next month.

Comment: The series will be starting in a couple weeks and running through October. The [sign up sheet](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1cy4VRQ7oxKcf0UYgXBcZiYR1d-CoEVRL-ozZq0RjvqM/edit?pli=1) is available to pick your week.

Answer (score 5):

I'd like to share mine as well.  I wonder if this couldn't be an ongoing thread, because frankly, I'd love to know the stories of pretty much everybody on here - even on the "other" side, like @Trig, @MarcGravell and @hammar!

Comment: For some reason I'm incapable of writing anything long at the moment. I have a list as long as your arm of essays (and letters to politicians) I want to write, for my own blog and for a couple of other places, and I've got nothing done in ages. I'd like to contribute to this, but I suspect it's unlikely.

Comment: The series will be starting in a couple weeks and running through October. The [sign up sheet](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1cy4VRQ7oxKcf0UYgXBcZiYR1d-CoEVRL-ozZq0RjvqM/edit?pli=1) is available to pick your week.

Answer (score 5):

I'll certainly be writing mine as well. Also looking forward to read the stories of others!

Comment: The series will be starting in a couple weeks and running through October. The [sign up sheet](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1cy4VRQ7oxKcf0UYgXBcZiYR1d-CoEVRL-ozZq0RjvqM/edit?pli=1) is available to pick your week.

Answer (score 4):

That could be very interesting - I'd be highly interested in participating

Comment: The series will be starting in a couple weeks and running through October. The [sign up sheet](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1cy4VRQ7oxKcf0UYgXBcZiYR1d-CoEVRL-ozZq0RjvqM/edit?pli=1) is available to pick your week.

Comment: Please make sure to log into the blog (you don't have to comment, just get your account associated) so I can give you permission to add a post.

Comment: @waxeagle - I believe I have associated my account properly

Comment: @BruceAlderman - added my name

Comment: @warren all set up now. You now have access as a Contributor

Comment: @waxeagle - btw, mine is written and has been "pending" for a couple weeks

Comment: @warren I was unware of this. I'll have El look at it an publish it this week

Answer (score 4):

My faith is a bundle of contradictions; I'd be glad to share my story.

Answer (score 3):

My story is mundane, God seems to have spoken to me mainly through the hives. But I figured I'll bump this topic up.

Comment: The series will be starting in a couple weeks and running through October. The [sign up sheet](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1cy4VRQ7oxKcf0UYgXBcZiYR1d-CoEVRL-ozZq0RjvqM/edit?pli=1) is available to pick your week.

Comment: No one's story is mundane. But if that was ever the case, that would encourage others with mundane stories... Especially in a period when dramatic testimonies get the spotlight and are therefore considered the norm.