# Reopen: Christianity as we know it today is not tolerant enough per Jesus and the bible?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

I changed the question around so now it's not subjective but asking for specific quotes from the bible.  Please consider reopening or suggest what would make it better.

https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/9683/christianity-as-we-know-it-today-is-not-tolerant-enough-per-jesus-and-the-bible

Comment: If you're going to make this a meta issue, at least linking people to the relevant question would be appreciated.

Comment: @Caleb, isn't this the proper method of getting a question reopened?  To move the discussion away from the question itself?

Comment: @JonEricson Caleb edited the comment from the question which had a link to the meta.  That's what I was thanking him for.  I'll add it here too.

Comment: @Dan Andrews: Thanks for the edit.  (I assumed sarcasm.  Oops!)

Comment: @DanAndrews: Yes raising the issue here for discussion is the proper method except in some really simple fix cases that could be just flagged for a moderator to unilaterally reopen. In this case I think community discussion is important because its involves issues we aren't all clear on.

Comment: @Caleb agreed since it was closed by a mod and not the community.

Comment: What part of this question (asking for suggestions) is -2?

Comment: @Dan Andrews: Reputation on meta.*.SE is particularly meaningless.  My guess is that people aren't interested in re-opening the question.  Here's a +1, if that helps you feel better. ;-)

Comment: @JonEricson I really don't care about rep.  Have a look at some of my questions and some of which I'm attempting to keep (one is -9).  What I believe is that a -1 *should* be a response to allude that a question shows little effort on the authors part, is not well formed, or generally there is something wrong with the question itself.  The fact that a person wants to avoid a question is not reason enough to downvote.

Comment: however, it's a good reason to leave a comment

Answer (score 4):

Just adding "per Jesus and the bible" doesn't magically fix a non constructive question, nor does it make an unfocused question into a focused one. For example the following is simply not constructive in spite of asking for a purely Biblical answer:

> What Bible verses can be used to show that Christians shouldn't dance?

Your topic is different, but the question pattern is about the same. People's doctrinal positions are going to inform their interpretations so much that it's almost useless to approach a topic that way.

Also, the rest of the question doesn't do anything to solidify or focus it. You have a current event, an opinion piece in the media and a random verse of your own thrown in? How would you expect somebody to come along and actually answer this? You seem to be pushing a very specific direction and yet your question doesn't give any framework for getting the answers you seek.

Most importantly, when it comes to quoting Bible verses in support of an idea, outside of an scholarly environment that deal with this as a hermeneutics issue, it's a free for all. **How would the verses quoted by crazy picketing fundamentalist, a beauty pageant contestant that glibly votes for world peace and a few dozen varying traditions with doctrinal mandates on opposite directions of this issue be judged as right or wrong?** You haven't offered anything to solve this by adding "quoted from the Bible".

It seems to me that this has elements of both #1 and #2 problematic question types that I talked about in [my answer to your previous meta post here](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1318/30).

**Edit:** In response to your latest edit...

> I don't exactly read that as, "Love one another as long as they have the same belief system as you."

This kind of statement in a question really makes it sound to me like you are asking this not to learn something for yourself but rather because you have something in mind to communicate something. I asked my fair share of those kind of questions here early one. They didn't work out well. They are nice and active but they just get messier and messier and drag things down and distract from other questions that have clear answers that people actually learn something new from rather than spending their energy trying to convince people their view is right.

Comment: I humbly disagree, but that doesn't matter, I suppose.  Looking for specific quotes from the bible *should* make it more specific.

Comment: Removed the "random" article and made the scripture tie in more.

Comment: Im posting because I want to make sure I understand and this may make your point...because I can ask in response to or answer this way "I didnt know Christianity was suppose to be tolerant "... and this is why it cant be asked for instance....also because the response would be to broad to "ones" interpretation...kinda like my quote presents...am I close???