# Reopen suggestions: Christianity, Judaism, and Islam worship the same God?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

I removed some of the "babble" in the top of the question.  What could I change to make this question acceptable?

https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/8851/christianity-judaism-and-islam-worship-the-same-god

Comment: +1 because `What could I change to make this question acceptable?` seems like exactly the right thing to ask.   I'll think about possible answers, I just don't have anything to suggest off the top of my head.

Answer (score 4):

I think that this question is pretty much a lost cause at this point and here's why:

### It's a discussion disguised as a question.

I think this paragraph from the [Philosophy FAQ](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/faq) sums up my concern about the question:

> Please note that this site is not a personal blog or a pulpit for you to express your own personal philosophical beliefs. This is a Q&A site for examining ideas and concepts in the field of philosophy. It's OK to have opinions (even those that might differ from the "mainstream"), but you need to express them in a constructive way. If you fail to do this, your contributions are subject to being edited or moderated so that they adopt a less hostile or confrontational point of view.

We've had a discussion about whether or not the God of Judaism, Christianity, and Islam is the same God and it's time to move on.  There are a lot of good answers that did their level best to answer the question, but ultimately it's not a question that can be answered.

I should also point out that you've asked the same question on [Mi Yodeya](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/18254/971), which was closed, and on [Islam.SE](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/1932/138) where you got three upvoted answers.  When combined with the 7(!) upvoted answers on this site, I don't see what could be left to be said.  By opening the question again, we are just continuing the discussion that we probably shouldn't have been having in the first place.

### It's a comparative religion question, not a Christianity question

Comparative religion questions don't work well on individual religion sites.  As Shmuel Brin [writes](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/831/971) on meta.Judaism.SE this type of question:

> Pushes away experts—experts would gravitate to websites which discuss technical questions in their field. Unless these questions are discussed in Jewish books (in which case they **should be** welcome), these are not the types of questions experts would want to see.

When casting about for a new question to ask, I wonder if you might find it helpful to look at historical Christianity or questions discussed in Christian books?

Comment: Caleb is talking about deleting questions that have no hope to be opened.  I don't think this question should be deleted and there's no good reason why it's closed.

Comment: @Dan Andrews: To be honest, I agree with him.  Did you notice that the question has 9 downvotes?  That's a lot of people who don't think the question is useful.  But let's see if other people have some suggestions for you.

Comment: they don't know what's good for them.  I think the question got downvote momentum.  Everyone likes to jump on the bandwagon sometimes.  Similarly there are question that are upvoted just because of the author and upvote momentum.  I would hate to see this question deleted even if it remains as an example of what not to do.

Comment: @Dan Andrews: Yeah.  Voting isn't fair.  I'd hate to lose some of the answers, but I'm having a hard time seeing what benefit there is to keeping the question otherwise.  It doesn't really work to keep questions around that aren't helpful to the site.  (See [this mess](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/reputation-and-historical-archives/).)

Comment: I guess I'm a little troubled with "I'd hate to lose some of the answers" (I assume helpful answers) and "it doesn't really work to keep questions around that aren't helpful to the site".  IMHO, bad question with good answers are still helpful... do you not think that someone else would ask this same question and we'd go through this exercise again?

Comment: @Dan Andrews: It seems the right course of action is to fix the question or [merge the answers](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/improved-question-merging/) into an open question.  I don't have any candidates for that, however.  Further, I don't have the energy to pursue it. :(

Comment: Good answers on a bad question? We have [a place for those](http://christianity.blogoverflow.com/).