Are certain answers differing from trinitarian views deleted to control information?
What purpose does closing my answer to the question How do Trinitarians distinguish whether the Hebrew bible is referring to the "being" or "person[s]" of God in the verses that declare oneness? serve?
It is said that if you restrict society's access to information and ideas, you can manipulate and control its beliefs.

Answers have to match the perspective asked about, not argue against it. This isn't some Trinitarian bias - we delete loads of Trinitarian answers on non-Trinitarian questions too.

@curiousdannii. Care to point out why my answer to that question does not match the perspective asked?

The question asked 'How do Trinitarians distinguish between [A] and [B] . . . .   etc.' I cannot see that you even attempted to answer how Trinitarians do anything. You simply questioned Trinitarianism as such. Trinitarian apologist [sic] should clarify their redefinition of words.

@NigelJ. The question asks "distinction between "person" and "being"?.. It also says "Under trinitarian hermeneutical approaches, these verses are not contrary to the trinity because they actually refer to the single being of God, not to the trinitarian multiplicity of persons..

Yes, there are four questions asked, which should have been asked separately. It has resulted in confusion. But the header is the one which should be answered, primarily.

@NigelJ. I answered the question which ask "distinction between "person" and "being"?.. It also says "Under trinitarian hermeneutical approaches, these verses are not contrary to the trinity because they actually refer to the single being of God, not to the trinitarian multiplicity of persons.."

As much as I would love to mod-hammer delete posts by heretics.  No, answers are not deleted to censor anyone, to misquote Flannery O'Connor "we're all positivists now". If you want to participate here, you need to think of the site in terms of bubbles, if the question is "What do Trinitarians Say?" You need to mainly write about Trinitarian belief as if it were true.
You can cite the Bible all day long, but you did not cite the Trinitarian exegesis, you used anti-Trinitarian exegesis
This is not the same as trying to use the words sects like LDS, Catholics, Jehovah's Witnesses etc... against them when trying to answer questions that might (conceivably) point out a logical fallacy in their belief system. Some users on the site do that and we have to consider it on a case-by-case basis.
The point is, if you use only the Bible as your primary source and only exegesis representative of the counterpoint, you're not answering the question from the point of view requested. If you could have used the words of St. Athanasius or St. Thomas Aquinas against them or something like that then you could participate in such a manner and we would excuse your correctness as being correct and in line with the rules and bylaws of the storied history of this site.

Why would I need to write trinitarian belief as if it were true? I cited trinitarian reasoning in my answer and tried to refutedit. Your answer you could have used the words of St. Athanasius or St. Thomas Aquinas against them or something like that (which you can't, because they're right. And you won't because if you read them, you'd start to disbelieve your own misapprehensions about the nature of God and your whole world would come crashing down) shows your inclination. 'as if it were true " because when examined,, the possibility of it being false is exposed.

@alex, "Why would I need to write trinitarian belief as if it were true?" because that is the rule that the Christianity stackexchange community came up with to prevent anarchy.

So "writing about trinitarian belief as if were true" (even though the possibility of it is false exist) because that is the rule that the Christianity stackexchange community came up with to prevent anarchy," appears like the controlling system favors trinitarian views and considers differing views as causing anarchy.

@AlexBalilo Nobody is forcing you to do something that is against your conscience. If a question  requires an answer which argues as if a thesis is true, then if you do not believe the thesis is true - just leave the question alone. It's not a 'controlling system' ;  it is a system which invites academic debate and objective analysis.

@NigelJ. How is deleting an answer considered inviting academic debate and objective analysis? Why would I write about it as if it were true (even though the possibility of it is false exist) because that is the rule that the Christianity stackexchange community came up with to prevent anarchy," appears like the controlling system favors trinitarian views and considers differing views as causing anarchy.

@alex the way it works is 1. if you act in good faith, you are entirely free to ask the question which you answered 2. you are free to answer your own question which you asked, but 3. that means you are not free to answer a question which was not asked.  This is how we maintain viewpoint neutrality and tolerance without allowing any one perspective to entirely dominate the site.  If you don't like the Trinity, you can hide or gray out the Trinity tag with your "Ignored Tags" filter on the right side of your screen.

" as if it were true" - I don't agree with this formulation. All you need to do is answer the question "What does denomination X Say?". If you cannot do that, and instead answer "What are arguments against what denomination X says?", then you simply failed at answering the question. The only truth that matters in your answer is whether "denomination X says Y". I really shouldn't change your answer at all whether or not you believe Y to be true.

@kut yeah, that's more or less what I mean, except I'm saying it a little more forcefully.  In my opinion the only truth that matters isn't whether "denomination X says Y" - its whether "denomination X believes Y" which is a distinction worth talking about.  There are lots of posts we delete based on that distinction.

@NigelJ. “it is a system which invites academic debate and objective analysis”.    No that is exactly the opposite of how this site is supposed to work!

@Kristopher Elaborate please

@kutschkem  https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1809/23657

@Kristopher And that is not saying "academic debate and objective analysis"? Maybe I am misunderstanding what you mean, or what you think NigelJ means.
